# Embedded custom scheme in android mail client not sent to resolver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing a app that needs to activate when clicked on a link in email body and extract token from the link. The problem is that the email client on Android doesn't send it to OS for resolving and the app doesn't get a chance to work on it and shows net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME instead.If I open a html file with the same link and tap on the link, everything works fine. 
My activity intent filter is:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ResetPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Reset Password"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="sns"></data>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>

            <data
                android:host="testserver"
                android:scheme="http"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Anybody knows any solution to this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not show the used link.

Comment: @greenapps: the link is sns://dummydomain/tokenstring

Comment: That is not a link. That is maybe an url. Please show how it is contained in an email body. Do you use a plain text body or a html body?

Comment: @greenapps: here is the full body of email (html)

Comment: Dear User
We have received your request to reset your password and now that your email address has been verified we are ready to continue the process.
Web site users
Please click on the link below and follow the on screen instructions.
- Please click here to continue resetting your password online now
Mobile application users
(here is an anchor to 'sns://requestresetpasswordtoken?token=af1ea5a7-a68f-4de3-9ca7-7a6bfbc8939d')

Comment: Sorry but i still see no (anchor) link. You say: `The problem is that the email client on Android doesn't send it to OS for resolving`. Ok. You mean when the user clicks a link? But I wonder if your email client displays it as a link to begin with. Does it display a (clickable) link or just the text?

Comment: Ok. I reread your post and it looks as if the email client displays a link and there happers something when clicked.

Comment: Mail client changes the anchor link to a normal text (none clickable)

Comment: If the user cannot click on it. So who is invoking your app? I don't understand. When does your app show `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, at first mail client shows it as a link and when you tap on it (so that mail client hand it over to [os] or browser), a dialog appears saying ERR-UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME inside mail client. (could it be by os ?)

Comment: So you don't know which app is showing that error?

Comment: It must be default mail client for sure (I don't have it right now with me to see further) as a wild guess I mentioned it might somehow be put there by OS.